# Excel: #NAME? appearing when linking/referencing other spreadsheets/workbook cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I'm updating a spreadsheet that refers to data in another worksheet *=NameofWorksheet* for some reason I get **#NAME?** in some of the cells, even when the actual path is correct.

The only way to overcome the problem is to open up the source spreadsheet and then recalculate the destination spreadsheet. But, if I then close the workbooks; open up just the destination workbook the #NAME? issue comes back.

I've even created a test destination spreadsheet and it doesn't suffer from the #NAME? problem.

Any reason for this? Should I be worried about the integrity of some Sheets?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Michael.

Comment: #NAME? in some of the cells? but not all?

Comment: Mike - I don't have an answer, but I have seen this when taking Excel worksheets from one platform to another and back (Windows/Macintosh).

Comment: are you sure the result referenced in the source sheet is not producing the error as well? like a total with errors not allowing a result?

Comment: #Name in some cells but not all is correct - but the row with the #NAME is refering to the same row of data from another book. The source worksheets all show the figures - but I'm wondering if some of those figures might not be in text format without someone realising...I'll need ot haev a look. Thanks for your views.

Comment: This error means that it's not recognizing a word used; or the Function is being used incorrectly (wrong number of arguments for example). This happens when the Super Duper Expert types in the formula without using the drop box and does something wrong, but knowing it's Perfect.